# factor of Riemann Zeta product formula must be zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

**Riemann Zeta as Euler Product**

As you likely know, the Riemann Zeta function, commonly expressed as a sum:

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$

can be written as an Euler product formula:

$$\zeta(s) = \prod_{p\ prime} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$

**Zeros**

For the Riemann Zeta function to be zero, this means at least one of those product factors must be zero:

$$\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = 0$$

**Flaw?**

Why is the above logic considered incorrect? Where is the flaw?

If it is indeed correct, then why don't mathematicians talk about proving the Riemann Hypothesis that non-trivial zeros lie on the $Re(s) = \frac{1}{2}$ line, by focussing on these factors, one of which must be zero?

Comment: The Euler product for the $\zeta$ function and the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}$ are converging only in the region $\text{Re}(s)>1$. When we talk about the zeroes of the $\zeta$ function, we mean the zeroes of the analytic continuation of such series.

Comment: And indeed, the Euler product shows that there are no zeros for $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: And of course, $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ **cannot** be zero.

Comment: Thanks Jack and Chappers .. I didn't understand that the definition is only for Re(s)>1. Can you point me to a blog/website explaining why this is the case?

Comment: And any pointers to learn about "analytic continuation" (for non-professional mathematicians) would be helpful.

Comment: @Tariq: Have you studied any complex analysis (or, for that matter, real analysis)? Those would likely be the best places to start.

Comment: hi @jd1 .. no I didn't do maths to any significant level

Comment: Maybe you are interested in *Week6Lecture4: The Riemann Zeta Function and the Riemann Hypothesis*, from the official channel **Petra Bonfert-Taylor**, from YouTube.

Answer (score 6):

Even ignoring the analytic continuation issue, you've made a fundamental error: treating infinite products in the same way as finite products.

While it is true that if a product of *finitely many* terms is zero, then one of the terms must be zero, this is *false* when we consider infinite products. Consider the product $1\cdot {1\over 2}\cdot {1\over 3}\cdot ...$; it's easy to show that this equals zero, even though each term is positive.

Remember that - just like an infinite sum - an infinite product is defined as a **limit**: $$\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} a_i=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i\le n} a_i.$$ If each $a_i$ is nonzero, then $\prod_{i\le n}a_i$ is nonzero - but the limit of a sequence of nonzero terms can be zero, so this doesn't stop the whole product from being zero.

(Along the same lines, you might consider why $0.999999...=1$ even though any *finite sequence* of $9s$ after the decimal point yields a number $<1$.)

Comment: thanks - that's the central point you've answered.